How can i implement sequlize inner join
I'm trying to implement an inner join to join my post and categories table, I have tried to console log the result for the listOfCategories and it just shows an empty array. The purpose of the listOfCategories constant is to show the post and on the post, it should show the categories on the post that is created. I am new to sequlize.js so I would appreciate any help on this.The category label should go underneath the like button
Post Model


module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const Posts = sequelize.define("Posts", {
    title: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
    },
    post: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
    },
    ingredients: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
    },
    CategoryId: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      allowNull: true,
      references: {
        model: "Categories",
        key: "id",
      },
    },
  });

  Posts.associate = (models) => {
    Posts.hasMany(models.Comments, {
      onDelete: "cascade",
    });

    Posts.hasMany(models.Likes, {
      onDelete: "cascade",
    });

    
    // Posts.hasMany(models.Categories, {
    //   foreignKey: "CategoryId",
    // });
    Posts.belongsTo(models.Categories, { foreignKey: "CategoryId" });
    //  Posts.belongsTo(models.Categories, { foreignKey: "CategoryId" });
  };
  
  return Posts;
};



Categories Model


module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const Categories = sequelize.define("Categories", {
    category_name: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
      distinct:true // add this distinct here
     },
    UserId: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      allowNull: true,
      references: {
        model: "Users",
        targetKey: "id",
      },
    },
  });
  
  Categories.associate = (models) => {
    Categories.hasMany(models.Posts, {
      onDelete: "cascade",
    });
 

     Categories.belongsTo(models.Users, { foreignKey: "UserId" });
  };
   
  return Categories;
};



Category Route


const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();
const { Categories } = require("../models");
 const { validateToken } = require("../middlewares/Authmiddlewares");
const { where } = require("sequelize");

router.get("/", async (req, res) => {
  const listOfCategories = await Categories.findAll();
  res.json(listOfCategories);
});

router.post("/", validateToken, async (req, res) => {
   const category = req.body
    category.UserId = req.user.id;

   if (!category) {
     res.status(400).send({
       error:
         "This category is in use by someone els, please try something else, thanks.",
     });
   } else {
   await Categories.create(category);
   res.json(category);
   }
});
 


module.exports = router;



Posts Route


const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();
const { Posts, Likes,Categories,Users } = require("../models");
const { validateToken } = require("../middlewares/Authmiddlewares");
 
router.get("/", validateToken, async (req, res) => {
  const listOfPosts = await Posts.findAll({ include: [Likes, Categories] });
  const listOfCategories = await Posts.findAll({
    attributes: [
      "id",
      "title",
      "post",
      "ingredients",
      "CategoryId",
      "createdAt",
      "updatedAt",
      "UserId",
    ],
    include: [
      {
        model: Categories,
        attributes: [
          ["id", "Categories.id"],
          ["category_name", "Categories.category_name"],
          ["UserId", "Categories.UserId"],
          ["createdAt", "Categories.createdAt"],
          ["updatedAt", "Categories.updatedAt"],
        ],
        required: true,
        logging: console.log, // Ensures INNER JOIN
      },
    ],
  });
 
  const likedPosts = await Likes.findAll({ where: { UserId: req.user.id } });
  
  res.json({
    listOfPosts: listOfPosts,
    likedPosts: likedPosts,
    listOfCategories:listOfCategories});

 });




]1

At least you should indicate the same foreignKey option in Categories.hasMany as you indicated in belongsTo
